# Fortify Often Misused: File upload Issue

Tags: html, fortify

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function fileValidation(fileInput) {  
            var filePath = fileInput.value;
            // Allowing file type
            // First check file type
            const fileTypes = [
              ".pdf",
              "file"
            ];
            if (!fileTypes.includes(fileInput.type)) {
                console.log("Invalid file input")
                fileInput.value = '';
                return false;
            }
            // Second check file content
            var fileContent = fileInput.files[0];
            if (fileContent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsText(fileContent);
                reader.onload = function (evt) {
                    console.log(reader.result)
                }
                reader.onerror = function (evt) {
                    console.log(reader.error)
                }
            }
            // Third check file size
            const fileSize = fileInput.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024; // in MiB
              if (fileSize > 2) {
                console.log('File size exceeds 2 MiB');
                return false;
              }
        }
    </script>
</head>
 
<body>
    <!-- File input field -->
    <label for="botFile">File upload</label>
    <input type="file" id="botFile" onchange="fileValidation(this)" maxlength="255" name="botFile" accept=".pdf" />
</body>

</html>
```

Fortify shows this recommendation to fix the issue

> Do not allow file uploads if they can be avoided. If a program must accept file uploads, then restrict the ability of an attacker to supply malicious content by only accepting the specific types of content the program expects. Most attacks that rely on uploaded content require that attackers be able to supply content of their choosing. Placing restrictions on the content the program will accept will greatly limit the range of possible attacks. Check file names, extensions, and file content to make sure they are all expected and acceptable for use by the application.

**Result:**
Tried several other fixes to resolve this  Issue. But fortify doesn't eliminate the issue.

Can anyone please suggest the fix/solution ?

Comment: What is "the issue" you try to fix?

Comment: @NicoHaase The issue Fortify shows up is "Permitting users to upload files can allow attackers to inject dangerous content or malicious code to run on the server", This is because of this line in the html  <input type="file" >. I tried to fix it as per the suggestions like Check file names, extensions, and file content. But it couldn't fix the issue on Fortify. So need help here...